# CSS Grid layout for 1 large image and 3 small

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I'm trying to rearrange this code to get this grid view like the screenshot.

I need the first image in the row to be full width 100%, then the second row I need 3 images of equal width in a row underneath.

[image]

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/gycmp21k/

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

li:first-child {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: related: https://css-tip.com/image-thumbnail/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images 2, 3 and 4 are the same width in your picture, so make them the same width.

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Image 1 and images 2, 3 and 4 are not the same hight in your picture, so don't make them the same height:

```
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
```

Image 1 spans across multiple **columns** not multiple rows in your picture, and it spans across 3 of them, not 2 of them

```
grid-column: span 3;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}

li:first-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can remove both grid-templates